# Angular custom scripts loader

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an Angular 7 CLI app which is served by ASP.NET MVC. 
In Index.cshtml file I have these lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/app/runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/app/polyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/app/scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/app/vendor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/app/main.js"></script>
```

Everything works fine.

However sometimes during development these files are not generated due to compilation errors etc.

I'm wondering is there a way to write a custom manual loader that will try to fetch these files and if any of these are not found will pop up a nice message to the developer.

Basically a really simple pre-loader to the application.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but you might consider developing your API separately from your frontend. I have several projects with an Angular frontend and ASP.NET Core WebAPI backend, and I find development is much easier when they're separate. (Assuming you have your API and Angular frontend in the same project. If not, disregard.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, what I do when it comes to altering the `index.html` is having a controller, which I call `SpaController` with an `Index` (default) action. Then, I load the `index.html` file (which is really small) and patch it with all the changes I want to apply. After being patched and downloaded on the browser, the rest of the communication is done through API REST, so it's just a small patch.

In your case, I would use that action of that controller I mentioned above and check if all the tag scripts are included. If not, you have flexibility to alter `index.html` and do what you want, like showing an error, or even stop the application.

Comment: Thank you. I did exactly what you wrote. Now if any of the required angular files are missing there is a message.